# Magento 2 Flush Cache Storage

Tags: magento2.1

When I Clicked on Flush Cache Storage, some of CSS & JS such as Custom.css, Owl Carousel CSS, Bootstrap CSS is not Showing when I Inspect the element & My Whole UI is disturbed. I'm using Smart-wave Porto theme. How to resolve.
Link: http://loredigital.net/merrimac-industrial/

Comment: please move your question to magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm seeing bootstrap loading and its classes having effects.